# How to analyse ordinal data for five food samples

Tags: spss, ordinal-data, likert, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I've conducted a questionnaire asking participants to rate biscuit samples based on factors such as taste and look. The ratings ranged from strongly like to strongly dislike. What is the best method to analyse/compare the ratings of different samples? For example, compare the appearance ratings of sample 1 with the appearance ratings of sample 2. Based on researching online, I was thinking about using Mood's Median Test and/or Wilcoxon Matched-pairs Signed-rank Test, but I'm uncertain if these are suitable.